# How can I apply str_split to a tibble with one character column?

Tags: r, tidyverse, strsplit

Suppose I have a tibble object with one character column; and I want to transform to the *target* by using str_split function. I cannot succeed in this. Any suggestions for that?

```
> as_tibble(c("sdsd/ffg","fdfd/rrrr/rrr","dfd/ww/rrr/ww"))%>%str_split("/")
[[1]]
[1] "c(\"sdsd"      "ffg\", \"fdfd" "rrrr"          "rrr\", \"dfd"  "ww"           
[6] "rrr"           "ww\")"        

Warning message:
In stri_split_regex(string, pattern, n = n, simplify = simplify,  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
> target <- str_split(c("sdsd/ffg","fdfd/rrrr/rrr","dfd/ww/rrr/ww"),"/")
> target
[[1]]
[1] "sdsd" "ffg" 

[[2]]
[1] "fdfd" "rrrr" "rrr" 

[[3]]
[1] "dfd" "ww"  "rrr" "ww"
```

Comment: when yo make it a tibble its like a data.frame. use `as_tibble(c("sdsd/ffg","fdfd/rrrr/rrr","dfd/ww/rrr/ww"))$value %>% str_split("/")` (becuase it calls its only column 'value')

Comment: Please clarify whether you want a tibble as the output? If so, I presume you would like to split your slash-separated strings into a fixed set of columns, as all rows in a given tibble must have the same columns. Perhaps editing your question to present the expected result would help.

Answer (score 1):

You could `pull` the column to get it as a vector and then apply `str_split`

```
tibble::as_tibble(c("sdsd/ffg","fdfd/rrrr/rrr","dfd/ww/rrr/ww")) %>% 
    dplyr::pull(value) %>%
    stringr::str_split("/")

#[[1]]
#[1] "sdsd" "ffg" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "fdfd" "rrrr" "rrr" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "dfd" "ww"  "rrr" "ww"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do the `str_split` inside `mutate` which returns a `list` column and then can be extracted with `value`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
as_tibble(c("sdsd/ffg","fdfd/rrrr/rrr","dfd/ww/rrr/ww")) %>%
    mutate(value = str_split(value, "/")) %>%
    pull(value)
#[[1]]
#[1] "sdsd" "ffg" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "fdfd" "rrrr" "rrr" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "dfd" "ww"  "rrr" "ww"
```